# Send MIDI events to a stand-alone sampler/synth

Tags: c++, audio, midi

I'd like to develop a very simple program to map PC keyboard to a piano keyboard: each time the user press a key a MIDI event is generated and a stand-alone sampler/synth (such as SFZ+ or other) receives these events and plays a sound.

I am able to generate MIDI events (using midiOutShortMsg), but they are sent directly to the FM synth (and so played by it), I'd like to send them to an external *software*. The code must be in C/C++.

Could you help me?

Tnx.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/)

> JACK is system for handling real-time,
>   low latency audio (and MIDI). It runs
>   on GNU/Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, OS X
>   and Windows (and can be ported to
>   other POSIX-conformant platforms). It
>   can connect a number of different
>   applications to an audio device, as
>   well as allowing them to share audio
>   between themselves. Its clients can
>   run in their own processes (ie. as
>   normal applications), or can they can
>   run within the JACK server (ie. as a
>   "plugin"). JACK also has support for
>   distributing audio processing across a
>   network, both fast & reliable LANs as
>   well as slower, less reliable WANs.
>
> JACK was designed from the ground up
>   for professional audio work, and its
>   design focuses on two key areas:
>   synchronous execution of all clients,
>   and low latency operation. More
>   background information is available.

Available as source or binaries [here](http://jackaudio.org/download).

Comment: Thank you! But I'd like to avoid third party libraries/frameworks. I was hoping to use only "mmsystem.h" and "Winmm.lib" or any other system libs (yes, I'm on Windows ;-)) Anyway, if it is not so difficult and heavy to use I can give a try!

Answer (score 0):

You must have used "midiOutOpen" to open the device. 
What if you select another device id ?

Comment: If I pass 0 as device ID the internal FM synth plays, if I pass 1 the program crashes! :-(

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are not opening the correct device. midiOutOpen takes a device ID as second parameter; did you check if the one you pass is the correct one (using  midiOutGetNumDevs and midiOutGetDevCaps)?

Comment: I launch SFZ+ before my app, and the method midiOutGetNumDevs returns 1 (just one device)! It seems my stand-alone sampler is not recognized!

Comment: How does that sampler get its input? Do you have to configure it to take its input from a hardware MIDI driver?

Comment: Ehm... This is a good question! I noticed that SFZ+ doesn't allow me to configure MIDI settings, when I click on MIDI menu nothing appears! Maybe because PC where I'm working has not any MIDI interface. Is it worth to install another sampler/synth?

Answer (score 0):

Many software synths don't set themselves up as Windows MIDI devices.  Try using the freeware [LoopBe1](http://www.nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html) to connect virtual cables between MIDI apps.